# Recursion on C++ that returning backwards

Tags: c++, recursion

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void countdown(int n);

int main(){
    countdown(4); // call the recursive function
    return 0;
}

void countdown(int n){
    cout << n << endl;

    if (n > 0){
        countdown(n-1); // function calls itself
    }

    cout << n << endl; // intended part of code
}
```

Simple run :

```
4
3
2
1
0
0
1
2
3
4
```

Question: why does this recursive function counts back up from 0 to 4 and do not stop at 0?

Comment: The counting backwards comes from the second cout call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because recursion function call is stored in stack. So, when one function call returns, it is popped out of stack and then it executes the next line of the function call.

```
void countdown(int n){
cout << n << endl; // This line calls 4 3 2 1 0

if (n > 0){
countdown(n-1); // function calls itself
}

cout << n << endl;; //This line print 0 1 2 3 4
}
```

Suppose the numbers before the line of the code are the line numbers:

```
 1   void countdown(int n){
 2   cout << n << endl; // This line calls 4 3 2 1 0

 3   if (n > 0){
 4    countdown(n-1); // function calls itself
 5   }

  6  cout << n << endl;; //This line print 0 1 2 3 4
  7  }

Suppose countdown is called with n = 2,
Then, Your stack will initially contain function call with n = 2.
Because of line 2, 2 gets printed. 
Because of line 4, function with n = 1 gets called. So, now stack has 1|2
Now because of line 2 again, 1 gets printed. 
Because of line 4, function with n = 0 gets called. So Now stack is 0|1|2
Line 2 prints 0.
Line 3 condition fails and so line 4 is not executed. 
Line 6 prints 0. 
Line 7 tells that function execution is over and hence it will pop out of stack. Now stack is 1|2.
Now, function with n = 1 resumes its operation from line 5. 
So, line 6 makes it print 1.
line 7 tells that function execution is over and hence it will pop out of stack. Now stack is 2. 
So, function with n =2 resumes its operation from line 5.
line 6 makes it print 2.
line 7 tells function execution is over and hence it will pop out of stack. And now it will return to main.
```

Comment: So it works in this order ? :
1. Recursion goes down (more usually) and prints numbers
2. The second cout calls the function again from the stack in queenie.

Comment: @Peter : Updated the answer with a detailed explaination.

Comment: @Peter : Please let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Why values are returned from the stack  and was not erased ?

Comment: @Peter: The values are erased from stack. If you see, the stack has been changing throughout the course.

Comment: I see that i'm at my limits here. The understanding i have now when the if part is false AND there is still code to execute in the function. The function starts to call it self using variables in the stack to fulfill the second cout.

Comment: The function is not calling itself to fulfill the second cout. It is just completing its execution and returning . Now since function with n=2 had called function with n = 1, so function with n= 1 after execution will return to function with n =2 and will resume its execution from the next line from  where it had left . So, in this case, it leaves at line 4, and hence resume from line 5.

Comment: Got it thank you very much. I see now that it is easy to stumble on big rock in the ground

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You print `n` twice - before calling the function recursively, and then again after it returns. If you only want to print the number counting down, just print it once:

```
void countdown(int n) {
    cout << n << endl;
    if (n > 0){
        countdown(n-1);
    }
    // Another cout call was removed here...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To put it very simply, calling a function - even your own function - does not end execution of the current function. Consider the following:

```
void countdown() {
    std::cout << countdown << "\n";
}

int main() {
    countdown();
    std::cout << "main\n";
}
```

you would not be surprised that this prints

```
countdown
main
```

Nor would you be surprised if you wrote:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    if (i == 0)
        countdown();
    std::cout << "main\n";
}
```

We can also simply demonstrate that a recursive function backtracks through its call points like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void countdown(int n) {
    std::cout << "countdown(" << n << ") entry\n";
    if (n == 0)
        countdown(n + 1);
    std::cout << "countdown(" << n << ") exit\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "main entry\n";
    countdown(0);
    std::cout << "main exit\n";
}
```

[live demo](http://ideone.com/gl52Ru)

outputs:

```
main entry
countdown(0) entry
countdown(1) entry
countdown(1) exit
countdown(0) exit
main exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two output lines. Remove the last `cout << n << endl`. That last line is what is counting back up, after returning from the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

because of the second cout just before the end of the coutdown function